# Framework7 pull-to-refresh-content not working in airplane mode

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

The whole thing just no longer working after I switch my iPhone to airplane mode.

No pull down arrow. No loading animation. Just cannot pull down. Should I handle network condition when using this feature? For example disable and enable pull to refresh after I check for network existence?

Framework7 1.5.0

```
<div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
    <!-- Page, "data-page" contains page name -->
    <div data-page="index" class="page">
      <!-- Scrollable page content -->
      <div class="page-content infinite-scroll pull-to-refresh-content">
        <div class="pull-to-refresh-layer">
          <div class="preloader"></div>
          <div class="pull-to-refresh-arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-block media-list topic-list">
          <ul id="topicListContainer">

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="infinite-scroll-preloader" style="display: none">
          <div class="preloader"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out by trail and error. Fix it by adding bottom toolbar.

```
        <!-- Bottom Toolbar-->
        <div class="toolbar">
            <div class="toolbar-inner">
                <!-- Toolbar links -->
                <a href="#" class="link">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#" class="link">Link 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```